# Cannot select element in JQuery and execute simple event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I cannot make a simple click event on the "canvas" using JQuery click function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("test");

    $("#canvas").click(function(){
        alert("canvas");
    });
    $(".middle").click(function(){
        alert("middle");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle">middle
        <div id="canvas">canvas</div>
</div>
```

"test" message is appearing but functions above is not working. Other siblings of div "middle" **(I did not include since I tried to remove them for testing and it still happening)** can execute events but only this div and inside cannot execute a single event.

Tried also to `console.log($("#canvas"))` and it fetches some data below.

> [div#canvas]

here is the complete html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="/demo/resources/themes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/demo/resources/themes/custom/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/demo/resources/themes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Sketchy-demo/resources/themes/custom/js/custom.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>App Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="middle">
            <div id="canvas"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

custom.css

```
.middle{
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 88%;
    width:100%;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#canvas{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 88%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 6%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px dashed black;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
```

Below is the image of the divs:[image]

This is really frustrating because this is a basic function that I cannot call.

Edit:

I added a https://jsfiddle.net/5mtt2khu/

Please let me know any questions.
Thanks!

Comment: When i run your code, i can get both alert canvas and middle just fine.

Comment: yeah, thats the point. its easy to see that it must work but it wasn't on mine

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi @ChrisG, its all the information I got. thanks

Comment: @bpunzalan Where's the CSS?

Comment: Its running on the snippets but it is not working on my machine.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle to check. thanks

Comment: It's this: `.middle { z-index: -1 }` It moves the `<div>` behind the `body`. Know how I found out? I right-clicked on the canvas and selected "inspect element", and I got taken to `<body>`.

Comment: yes! Thank you! :) thanks for the tip on the "inspect element" thing. This is really helpful in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do with `event.target` element .And match with condition

[**Updated js Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5mtt2khu/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 alert("test");
  
  $(".middle").click(function(e) { 
if($(e.target).attr('id')== 'canvas'){
alert('canvas')
//do stuff for canvas
}
else{
 alert("middle");
//do stuff for middle
}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle">middle
  <div id="canvas">canvas</div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

> Remove or change the `z-index`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("test");
  $(".middle").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') == 'canvas') {
      alert('canvas')
      //do stuff for canvas
    } else {
      alert("middle");
      //do stuff for middle
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.middle {
 z-index:0;/*remove or change > -1*/
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 88%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 88%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 6%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px dashed black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle">
  <div id="canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: still no output.

Comment: i was added with `console.log()` check the `F12` mode of the browser. Or change with console.log to `alert()`.See my updated answer

Comment: Still no output. (e) doesn't returning anything.

Comment: Buts its working on the snippet.check the jquery link or try with `event` instead of `e` and `event.target` instead of `e.target`

Comment: its running on the snippets but not working on my workspace

Comment: @bpunzalan I already told change the `z-index:0` .see the fixed fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5mtt2khu/1/ .And check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work.

So the problem must come from other things. Here is some possibilities :

- JQuery is not correctly installed
- You have a javascript error before so this is never executed
- Your html is dynamically added after you load the event handler
- You have an other div with the same id somewhere

---

If your html is dynamically added, I recommend you to do something like this

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $(document).on ("click", "#canvas", function () {
        alert("canvas");
    });

    $(document).on ("click", "#middle", function () {
        alert("middle");
    });

});
```

If you have several "canvas" id, you can do something like :

```
$("[id=canvas]").click(function () {
    alert("canvas");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("test");

  $("#canvas").click(function(e){
      alert("canvas");
      e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(".middle").click(function(){
      alert("middle");
  });
});
```

```css
.middle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

#canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle">
  <div id="canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="middle">
        <div  id="canvas" style="width:10px;height:10px;background:red;"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("test");

    $("#canvas").click(function(){
        alert("canvas");
    });
    $(".middle").click(function(){
        alert("middle");
    });
});
</script>
```

Try to change the div to input type or button.It works when I specified the color to the div and clicking it.So, without knowing where to click the event was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code is actually working fine as it should. The problem here is propably because the canvas has no height and width defined, so it's too small to actually be able to click on it.
Give the divs a height and width like the below code snippet and you'll see that the jQuery gets executed correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("test");

    $("#canvas").click(function(){
        alert("canvas");
    });
    $(".middle").click(function(){
        alert("middle");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 50px; width: 100px;">
        <div id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 15px; width: 30px;"></div>
</div>
```